# NO directory, logging in with HOME=/

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, vmware-player

I checked by doing :

```
cd /
```

then

```
cd home
```

after ls shows my directory malik

```
ls

malik
```

as shown in picture as well :

[image]

But I don't know why it is saying "No directory, logging in with" ?

Comment: Can you please paste the malik directory permissions and your /etc/passwd entry for user malik?

Comment: do mean ls?????

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 jul 2 04:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Dec 14 23:11 ..
drw----------31 malik malik 4096 Dec 02:08 malik

Comment: is that u mean???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directory permissons says

Owner: root, Group: root, Others: cannot access

I think you created the directory as user root.

Change the directorys permissons with

```
sudo chown malik.malik /home/malik
```

The sudo command gives you temporary root permissons for a specified command. If you want to get temporary root permissons for more than one command use

```
sudo su
```

[Take a look here about linux file / directory permissons (LPIC)](https://www.lpice.eu/en/home/linux-tip-of-the-month/04-2013///)

About the seconde error message:
    su - malik

It seams to me that you have not set a home directory for the user malik. You find this settings in /etc/passwd. It should look like

```
malik:x:1000:1000:malik:/home/malik:/bin/bash
```

Hope that helps.

Best, me